# Performance issue with iText 5.5.13 and heap space issue

Tags: java, itext

I am using iText 2.1.7 in Java to generate PDF.

I was using `HTMLWorker.parseToList(Reader, StyleSheet)` to convert part to String which contains HTML tags like Bold, Italic, href etc to PDF. For example, strings like "This is test  bold  text" to convert part of text to be bold.

The performance was good with `HTMLWorker`.

Now I mam upgraded to iText 5.5.13 as per requirement and I started using `XMLWorkerHelper.parseXHtml()` and I found the performance is very very bad compared to `HTMLWorker` and consuming more heap space.

If anyone has any idea about the solution or any other workaround, please let me know.

Comment: `HTMLWorker` is very simple and only supports a small subset of html. `XMLWorker` supports a larger subset of html. The downside is that that allowed `HTMLWorker` to be faster and less resource hungry.

Comment: Is there any way to improve performance for XMLworker and  heap space issue

Comment: How does your performance compare in iText 7 + pdfHTML?

Comment: I am generating PDF reports from XML file and generating around 250 PDF reports .Total time taken using Itext 2  (html worker ) 12 min  and no heap space issue . bUt while generating reports using Itext 5.5.13 ,its taking around 40 min and consuming heap space .

Comment: What needs the most time? Did you analyze it? Do you know if there are some images created? Like pngs or is it only html/text etc.?

Comment: hey. if you are migrating away from iText 2, there shouldn't be a reason to stop at iText 5, instead of iText 7 and pdfHTML. Any reason for this?

Comment: Currently Itext5.5.13 is  live in  production ,Will move to Itext 7 in future ,But currently  we need to close Heap space spike issue .Any suggestion how to overcome the Heap space issue .